# Is it possible to include fonts in an app bundle and make them available in a UIWebView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I'm working on some HTML5 content to be included as part of an iPad app in a Web View and it requires some custom fonts which I was attepting to implement via CSS and `@font-face`

As I understand it, Mobile Safari only supports SVG fonts, but my testing has shown Mobile Safari to really struggle with SVG and the performance hit is a serious issue.

So... is it possible to put fonts in the App Bundle and somehow make them available to the webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Include the fonts in the App Bundle and in the app-info.plist use

"Fonts provided by application"

and provide the file name for each font.

Looks something like this...

---

[image]

Comment: This is good solution but nowdays this semms not to work in iOS5. Is there are new ideas?